# Error found :missing argument to -exec

Tags: cygwin

I have used:

```
find ./components -iname \"*.html\" -exec rsync -R '{}' ./build/ \\;
```

which worked perfectly fine in Linux but now I am unable to run it in windows using cygwin. It gives an error:

> missing argument to `-exec'

Even used:

```
find ./components -iname \"*.html\" -exec rsync -R ./build/;
```

but unable to build html file.

I even tried:

```
find ./components -iname \"*.html\" -exec rsync -R '{}' ./build/;
```

but gives an error:

> skip directory

Answer (score 0):

Your escapes appear to be escaping the wrong thing:

1. `\\;` yields `\;`
2. `;` yields a token for the shell itself
3. `\;` yields `;` (Use this one)

So your command is:

```
find ./components -iname "*.html" -exec rsync -R '{}' ./build/ \;
```